# Creating a list of (kxn) matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I am trying to perform a K-mean  algorithm to obtain a lowest cost which would result in a KxN matrix. The value of K is determined by number of clusters the algorithm creates with optimal cost. For example, K=2 would imply 2 clusters ( or 2 centroids ) while N is the number of features. The K-mean is run in a loop for K=1 to 10 and the loop stops when best optimal cost is obtained for a particular value of K.  for example if an optimal cost is obtained for K=2, the centroid returned would be an 2xN matrix. I want to store all the centroids returned by the loop into a list. Please note that in every increment of loop the value of K would change by k=K+1. Therefore my centroid returned would be of size 1xN, 2xN, 3xN.
How to store this into a list such that I can get something like this:-

```
List= [[10,12,13], [[10,20,30],[1,2,3]], [[5,6,9],[4,12,20],[40,50,60]],...
```

With every loop I return a KxN matrix which I want to store it into a list. I want to access the list later by an index , say List[i] to retrieve the KxN matrix. 
I am mostly working with numpy. 
any suggestions would be a big help.

Comment: This question is to broad.  Please consider editing it, you haven't asked a specific question about a specific problem you've had.

Comment: I was giving explanation why I need to store a KxN matrix into a list where K is variable while N is constant.  Sorry if it sounded broad and  generic. Bottom-line is I need to store KxN matrices into a list

Comment: Then you should be asking that question (which in itself is a duplicate), check the related questions, your answer is going to be there.  Also be sure to show your attempt next time, right now it just looks like your asking us to do everything for you.

Comment: You can used numpy for the matrices, but not the outer list. So `[np.empty((1,N)), np.empty((2,N)), np.empty((3,N)), ...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
N = 5
lst = []
for K in range(1,11):
    lst.append(np.empty((K,N)))
```